# How to skip certain numbers in a for-loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, numbers, output, skip

I started practicing a for loop in C and so far I understand the main principle behind it. But I can't figure out how to get the following output:

```
1 2 3  5 6 7  9 10 11 ...
```

I managed to print 1 to 12 with the following for loop but how can I skip 4 and 8 or how to skip any number in general?

```
for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: Like `for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++) { if (i == 4 || i == 8) continue; printf("%d", i); }` ?

Comment: `if(i != 4 && i != 8) printf("%d", i);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest solution would be to check with an if statement for any values that you don't want.
if you have a rule like not printing all numbers that are divisible by 4 you can make your if statement like this

```
if(i % 4 == 0)
{
   //print
}
```

there is no way to do it specifically with the for loop expression.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use an if statement inside the body of the loop like

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 12; i++ )
{
    if ( i % 4 != 0 )
    {
        printf( "%d ", i );
    }
}
```

Or you can avoid the numbers that divisible by 4 in the third expression of the for loop like

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 12; i += ( i + 1 ) % 4 == 0 ? 2 : 1 )  
{
    printf( "%d ", i );
}
```

If you need to output the space character instead of a number divisible by 4 you can use an if-else statement inside the body of the loop. For example

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 12; i++ )
{
    if ( i % 4 != 0 )
    {
        printf( "%d ", i );
    }
    else
    {
        putchar( ' ' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do specific numbers you just add more conditions to the if statement:

```
    for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if(i != 11 && i != 5 && i%3 != 0)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, especially for a large amount of irregular exceptions, is the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int exceptionsv[] = {4, 8};
    int exceptionsc = sizeof(exceptionsv)/sizeof(exceptionsv[0]);
    
    for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < exceptionsc; j++)
        {
            if(exceptionsv[j] == i) i++;
        }
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (char i=0; i<12; i++) { if (i%4 != 0) printf("%d", i); }
```

Or you can isolate the pattern and duplicate it using a nested loop :

```
char patternCount = 3;
for (char i=0; i<patternCount; i++) { 
    for (char j=1; j<4; j++) printf("%d", i*4 + j); 
}
```